# Is Matrix Multiplication Commutative if $AB=0$ such that $A\neq0$ and $B\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Proposal:

> $$AB= 0=BA \iff A=0, \; B=0$$

**My attempt**

Assume $AB=0$ and $BA=0$ s.t  $A\neq 0$ and $B\neq0$. $A$ and $B$ must be $n\times n$ square matrices to be commutative.
Let  $AB=X$ and $BA=Y$

For Entry $x_{ij}$

$$x_{ij}=\sum^n_{k=1} a_{ik}b_{kj}$$

For Entry $y_{ij}$

$$y_{ij}=\sum^n_{k=1} a_{kj}b_{ik}$$

For statement to hold $x_{ij}=y_{ij}=0 \;\forall i,j, \in {\rm I\!F_n}$

I do not know how to continue with the proof. I have tried exclusively doing a $2\times2$ case with no luck. Is there already a proof of this? How do I continue?

Comment: How about $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: There exist nilpotent matrices as well. That already disproves your claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Counterexample*:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$